# Method Not Being Called in Class

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm using NAudio library and having an issue calling a method. I created a class for playback of the audio files and am assigning a bool value to a button click. Everything works fine with the exception of the IF part of my code will run up until the call to the method (line of the if code). No error is generated, its just not going to the OnPlaybackStopped method. I was outputting some text as well so I could confirm this and also see the PlaybackStopped is in face true in both cases. The ELSE portion runs no problem and actually calls the method without issue once the end of the file is reached. Any thoughts? I know I'm probably just missing something easy here and just need another set of eyes to tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
namespace AudioTool
{
    public class Playback
    {
        private IWavePlayer _audioPlayback { get; set; }
        private AudioFileReader _audioReader { get; set; }
        private WaveViewer _waveViewer { get; set; }
        private Button _playButton { get; set; }
        private Button _stopButton { get; set; }
        private bool _stopButtonClick { get; set; }

        public Playback(IWavePlayer audioPlayback, AudioFileReader audioReader, WaveViewer waveViewer, Button playButton, Button stopButton, bool stopButtonClick)
        {
            _audioPlayback = audioPlayback;
            _audioReader = audioReader;
            _waveViewer = waveViewer;
            _playButton = playButton;
            _stopButton = stopButton;
            _stopButtonClick = stopButtonClick;
        }

        public void CreateAudioPlayback(string audioPath)
        {
            string fullAudioPath = (audioPath);
            _audioPlayback = new WaveOut();
            _audioReader = new AudioFileReader(fullAudioPath);
            _audioPlayback.Init(_audioReader);

            if (_stopButtonClick == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(_stopButtonClick);
                Console.WriteLine(_audioPlayback.PlaybackState);
                _audioPlayback.PlaybackStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(OnPlaybackStopped);
            }

            else
            {
                // Get file path and playback
                _audioPlayback.PlaybackStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(OnPlaybackStopped);
                _audioPlayback.Play();


                // View the waveform of the report
                _waveViewer.WaveStream = new WaveFileReader(fullAudioPath);
            }
        }

        private void OnPlaybackStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
        {
            _waveViewer.WaveStream.Dispose();
            _audioPlayback.Stop();
            _audioPlayback.Dispose();
            _audioReader.Dispose();
            _waveViewer.WaveStream = null;
            _audioPlayback = null;
            _audioReader = null;
            _playButton.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect the event to trigger? Presumably you either need to call `Play` and have it play to the end of the stream, or call `Stop`, right?

Comment: I actually had _audioPlayback.Stop(); in there are one point as well prior to calling the method, however, it made no difference. I removed it prior to posting here though. When I write the status of Playbackstopped out to console I do see it showing as Stopped but still doesn't trigger.

Comment: Could you try putting `_audioPlayback.Play()` directly after adding the event handler inside the `if` block and see if it triggers when the playback finishes?

Comment: As an aside: you shouldn't be constantly adding to event handlers. The multicast delegate will begin leaking very quickly.. Add the events once at program startup.

Comment: If I add _audioPlayback.Play() in the IF block it doesn't trigger. This is expected because I'm setting the bool value in a different class so in that case _stopButtonClick == false, but when I click the stop button it changes _stopButtonClick == true. I can include some Console.Write commands at every point in the IF statement and all are returned as expected, even the one after where I'm trying to call the method.

Comment: Okay. I'm not 100% because I'm not familiar with naudio, but I suspect the problem is that the event only gets fired when the playback first actually stops, and that you're adding the event handler after point. Could you not just directly call `OnPlaybackStopped()` from that line instead?

Comment: Simon... if you have another way of accomplishing it then I'm open. The issue I had was if I didn't do it this way then the case where I don't press the stop button, the playback would end immediatley and not actually wait for the recording to complete. The Playbackstatus always shows as stopped for some reason even though audio is still playing, though the function for that portion is working as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what was going on. When I clicked the Play button on one class (we'll call it main.cs) it began playing the audio via WaveOut in one audio stream. Then when I click the stop button in main.cs it was attempting to stop a new audio stream. So the functions related to audio such as stop had seemingly no affect because they were always trying to stop an audio stream that didn't have anything yet playing.

What I did to work around this problem was to add a few more lines of code to the main.cs so that the WaveOut was defined there, then each of the Play and Stop button clicks would then reference the class with the rest of the code.